# How to use a lambda expression to find a string in a list

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am trying to use a lambda expression to find a string within a list of items in a list.  I am getting a instance not set to an object error.

Refer to this simple class as an example

```
Public Class Project
Public ProjectList as New List(Of ProjectType)
End Class

Public Class ProjectType
Public Name As String
End Class
```

In My Code:

```
Dim MyProjectCollection as New List(of Project)
Dim MyProjectType as New ProjectType
MyProjectType.Name = "Math" 
MyProjectCollection.ProjectList.AddItem(MyProjectType) 'adding items to the Project
```

i am trying to filter out only "Science" Projects like this

```
MyProjectCollection.RemoveAll(function(x as Project) x.ProjectType.Name <> "Science")
```

it errors, if anyone can point me to what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.  I know I didn't add a ProjectType.Name = "Science" but just assume its a list already filled.

I want to remove all Projects where none of the ProjectTypes have a Name of "Science"

Comment: That second code snippet can't possibly compile. `MyProjectCollection` is type `List(Of Project)`, therefore `MyProjectCollection.ProjectList` is simply not a thing. Create a real example and run it yourself to reproduce the issue, then copy that code from the IDE into your question.

Comment: I fixed it.  sorry for that

Comment: Now the third snippet couldn't compile. `x` is type `Project`, therefore `x.ProjectType` is not a thing that exists. Also, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Explain what you're actually trying to achieve. The code is apparently trying to remove `Project` object from a collection but a single `Project` can have multiple `ProjectTypes`, so how exactly do you want to match? Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to remove all `Projects` where none of its `ProjectTypes` have a `Name` of `Science`? Provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: That is spot on  I want to remove all Projects where none of the projects types have a name of science.  You are correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.exists?view=net-5.0) in a second Lambda:

```
MyProjectCollection.RemoveAll(Function(p as Project) Not p.ProjectList.Exists(Function(pt As ProjectType) pt.Name = "Science"))
```

The first Lambda iterates over all `Project` objects in your list. The second Lambda checks if the `Project`'s `ProjectList` contains a `ProjectType` with `Science` as its `Name`. This second Lambda will return `True` if Science exists. You can use `Not` to reverse that result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your classes to Properties not Fields.

Declare 2 `ProjectType` variables and set their `Name` properties.

Declare a `Project` variable.

Add the 2 `ProjectType` variables to the `Project.ProjectList`

Now do the `RemoveAll` method.

```
Public Class Project
    Public Property ProjectList As New List(Of ProjectType)
End Class

Public Class ProjectType
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyProjectType As New ProjectType
    MyProjectType.Name = "Math"
    Dim MyProjectType2 As New ProjectType
    MyProjectType2.Name = "Science"
    Dim Prj As New Project
    Prj.ProjectList.Add(MyProjectType) 'adding items to the Project's ProjectList
    Prj.ProjectList.Add(MyProjectType2)
    Debug.Print("List before remove")
    For Each pt As ProjectType In Prj.ProjectList
        Debug.Print(pt.Name)
    Next
    Prj.ProjectList.RemoveAll(Function(x As ProjectType) x.Name <> "Science")
    Debug.Print("List after remove")
    For Each pt As ProjectType In Prj.ProjectList
        Debug.Print(pt.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

I have added a test loop before and after the remove. The results in the immediate window look like this.

```
List before remove 
Math 
Science 
List after remove 
Science
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```vb
MyProjectCollection.RemoveAll(Function(p) p.ProjectList.All(Function(pt) pt.Name <> "Science")))
```